# trouble in generating json with php in desired format

Tags: php, json

I am working with JSON for first time for a practice android application project. I found a tutorial where a ready json string is used which looks like this:

```
{
  "movies": [
{
  "movie": "Avengers",
  "year": 2012,
  "rating": 7.8,
  "duration": "141 min",
  "director": "Joss Whedon",
  "tagline": "A new age begins",
  "cast": [
    {
      "name": "Robert Downey Jr."
    },
    {
      "name": "Chris Evans"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mark Ruffalo"
    }
  ],
  "image": "http://jsonparsing.parseapp.com/jsonData/images/avengers.jpg",
  "story": "When Tony Stark and Bruce Banner try to jump-start a dormant peacekeeping program called Ultron, things go horribly wrong and it's up to Earth's Mightiest Heroes to stop the villainous Ultron from enacting his terrible plans."
} 
]
}
```

I followed the tutorial and was able to make it work as in videos. Even added few of my own ideas to it and app worked properly.

Now i am trying to generate my own json using php rest api. I have taken 4 rows from a mysql table and then sending the data as json to the app. But the json i am generating is not in the same format as in tutorial. 
Here is my json

```
{
  "0": {
"student_fees_id": "23",
"enrollment_number": "1703",
"semester_id": "3",
"fees_type_id": "4",
"paid_amount": "10000",
"balance_amount": "30000",
"status": "Pending",
"timestamp": "13 Aug 2016 @ 14:15:21"
  },}
```

and this is how i am generating it:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `student_fees` WHERE `enrollment_number` = '$er_id' ORDER BY `student_fees_id` DESC";
if($query_run= mysql_query($query)){ 


 while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
    $response[]=$r;
 }
 echo json_encode($response,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

How do I get it in proper format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I found the answer to my question!! After playing for a while with different methods of encoding json with php and repeatedly posting it in postman, I got it!

I am doing this now:

```
  for($i=0; $i<$row; $i++){

    $response[$i]['student_id'] = mysql_result($query_run, $i, 'student_id');
    $response[$i]['enrollment_number'] = mysql_result($query_run, $i, 'enrollment_number');

}
```

and then I send the *$response* array through json encode function and simply parse it in the app! This issue is solved for me! If any one has a better solution, i am open for new or even perfect / proper solution(s)!

Thank you everyone!